# Control a reference in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, linq-to-entities

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E7uk.png)Control a reference in entity framework

Open question .Net Core 5 - Entities.

What do you think is the most efficient way to work in MVC mode, having 1 single entity that references itself. example

```
 public class ClassGroupAndSubgroup
 {
    
     public int ID { get; set; }

    public int SubGroupId { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
```

}

```
ClassGroupAndSubgroup principalGroup { SubGroupId = 0, Name ="Principal"}; ----> Id = 1 (AutoNum)
ClassGroupAndSubgroup SubGroup { SubGroupId = 1, Name ="Item_1_Subgroup1"}; ----> Id = 2 (AutoNum)
ClassGroupAndSubgroup SubGroup_Two { SubGroupId = 1, Name ="Item_2_Subgroup1"}; ----> Id = 3 (AutoNum)
ClassGroupAndSubgroup principalGroup { SubGroupId = 3, Name ="Item_1_Subgroup2"};----> Id = 4 (AutoNum)
```

What I want is to make reference on itself, but from EntityFramework Core. I did it a long time ago with algorithms in C# and SQL but I can't do it in entity

Answer (score 0):

You want the Foreign Key property to refer to the parent, not the child, eg

```
 public class Foo
 {
    
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ParentFooId{ get; set; }

    public Foo Parent {get;set;}

    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hola, la pregunta esta guiada al algoritmo que controla esa Auto-referencia, como hacerlo eficiente ?